# Cakephp 2x using debug($this) inside a action

Tags: debugging, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi i am new to cakephp and i want to use "debug" in order to have a better view about the framework structure.

If i use var_dump($this) , inside a action, the page takes a long time to load and end up with a non structured data on screen.

I found that "debug" function shows a more elegant structure, but if i use debug($this) inside the action i end up with the well known php stack overflow :) " Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 113621911 bytes) "

How can i work around this ?

---

I've made a more specific debug and it worked just fine.

Comment: i know this is a php memory restriction, thta can be modified, but the app is located in a shared host.

Comment: It's quite rare to get out of memory dumping a controller instance, indicates either a recursive reference or massive amounts of data. You can work around it by dumping something more specific like `debug ($this->data)` i.e. debug _something_ not _everything_.

Comment: thanks AD7six, the recursive is -1 in all models, and there are just quite a few records on db. My intention is to have a complete view about the object, how data is fetched on db and how it is transfered through the mvc layers

Comment: you aren't going to get that dumping a controller instance; you are better off simply installing debug kit and investigating.

Comment: You can try `Debugger::exportVar()` which allows you to specify recursion depth: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Debugger.html#_exportVar  (but as @AD7six mentioned, that won't help figuring out the flow,  `Debugger::trace()` can at least show you the path so far...)

Comment: What about the debugkit plugin https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit , he will gives you the most needed informations about your controller (request,data,..)